# htaccess - Why aren't my rewrite rules working?

Tags: php, .htaccess

There's some misconfiguration in my htaccess which I can't solve :/

Here's the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 

rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [NC]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,L]
```

The .htaccess actually works fine, except in one case: When I connect to a subpage to the root domain without "www.", like this:

```
http://domain.com/somestuff
```

Then the first rule doesn't apply and I get redirected to:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=somestuff
```

What have I done wrong?? Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1`

below

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,L]`

Comment: don't feel stupid, just don't ever give up. btw, might I suggest you change the title to something more relevant. this may help other people who are struggling with rewrites. perhaps something as simple as "htaccess rewrite rules not working" or somethign along those lines?